# Getting an error, How can i use GSAP with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap, scrolltrigger, locomotive-scroll

error:

[image]

my main.js component:

[image]

I installed all libraries of gsap, locomotive, scrollTriger, but yet i m getting this error. i was expecting to make my scroll smooth and moving my heading tags when triggered by the scroll. But i'm just getting an error

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, error or other text. Copy the original text to your question instead.